# mysql if data no exist for in order dates

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
EXTRACT( DAY FROM date) AS day,
EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date) AS month, who, sum ( wsd ) AS total FROM weekly
WHERE season = '08'
AND status = 1
AND who = 'NAME SURNAME'
GROUP BY day, month


day month who           total
12  8     NAME SURNAME  18
```

I am getting totals of "wsd" column for every person in "who" column per day. If one person doesn't have records in table for a day, we can not see that name in the results as expected.

But i want to see that records too, with date and name with "0" in total column.

How can i do it with mysql only?

Comment: can you share table structure or create an sqlfiddle so that we can try to provide you solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, you can move the conditional logic from the `where` to the aggregation -- assuming that you have data for someone on every day:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( DAY FROM date) AS day, EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date) AS month, who,
       sum(case when status = 1 AND who = 'NAME SURNAME' then wsd else 0 end) AS total
FROM weekly
WHERE season = '08'
GROUP BY day, month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Coalesce or Isnull for inserting default values(in your case 0) ?